# SharePoint Auth token - Saving a formular

Tags: sharepoint, internet-explorer-11, http-status-code-403, sharepoint-2016

Our project team is currently working on a workspace hosted app on SharePoint 2016. In the application, we have a formula where the user can enter information and save them to a list (REST API).

**Now the problem:**
SharePoint does have an auth token which is expiring after a certain amount of time. If the token expired and we try to save the data of the formula to the list, the Internet Explorer (V.11) throws an HTTP 403 (Forbidden) error.

In Chrome, this doesn't happen. There, the token updates and the data get saved to the list as expected.

Does anyone have a solution or workaround for this problem?

Thank you all for your ideas and have a nice day!

Sincerely yours,
Raphael

*UPDATE*
We found out, that the create doesn't work in Chrome as well. But the update does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the token for the create request is refreshed too late and the request is send with the old token. Maybe you need to await the token update?

Best wishes
Simon